# Is there a `git-dropbox` or equivalent?

Tags: git, version-control, git-svn, dropbox

I know there are many tutorials to use Dropbox as a Git repository, but I do want to know is how to recommend non-technical staffs to commit their changes.

So it would be nice if I can `git-fetch` all change history from Dropbox, merge/resolve conflicts and then commit them back to Dropbox as well as what `git-svn` does.

Does this make sense?

I am almost ready to give up convincing all co-workers to use VCS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using macs, Github has a very nice graphical [desktop application](http://mac.github.com/) that makes using git super-easy for non-technical users. They plan to expand to Windows too, but it's not at that point yet (most of the userbase use macs, apparently, so they went for that first).

This is as easy to use as a Dropbox equivalent and you can just drag a folder form Finder onto the application and it'll make it into a new git repo ready for you to press the 'sync' button and send it to your account. You'll need a paid Github account if you want the stuff to be private of course, but it's only $7 a month, so not a bad option.

Comment: I've just installed github for mac and I found it looks pretty good!  It reminds me of [Tower](http://www.git-tower.com/).

Answer (score 1):

For using dropbox as repo just make folder and in this dropbox folder

```
git init --bare --shared=all
```

but i would not recommend this as professional setup. Git does not give you that much of edge if you use this as central repo. For them to commit there changes, just merge for them and they can commit there own branches at any time without conflicts.

Comment: Yes, I think you have a point.  Conflicts are everywhere and it won't be resolved by DropBox itself.  Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

> I do want to know is how to recommend non-technical staffs to commit their changes

Non-technical staffs **must don't use Git** at all (at least while Mac GitHub still unported)